# Scaffolding and CSS in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

I made a blogpost with two entries (`title`, `content`) like this

```
rails generate scaffold Post title:string content:text
```

This works, but

1. What if I want to add a new input area later? Ex. `author` field or something. Where do I add more fields to my Post scaffold?
2. I made a stylesheet `style.css` inside my public directory. Its just sitting there. How do I link it to my file in `app/views/post/new.html.erb` for example?
3. Where can I learn all the tweaks for scaffolding a specific field? Ex. I want the `title` input field to not contain special characters (ex. `@#$%`) or not be more than certain length.

I am using windows and rails 3.2.8.

Comment: If you have 3 questions, please ask 3 separate questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 3 in 1 question :)

#### 1st answer

As others said you need to modify your table to have the new fields, and this can be easily done with a [**migration**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html):

```
rails generate migration AddAuthorToPost author:string
```

But you also need to modify your views, because it won't contain the new field. The corresponding views are in `app/views/posts` (look for `edit.html.erb` and `new.html.erb`).

Of course you'll need to run your migration on your database:

```
rake db:migrate
```

#### 2nd answer

You can add your stylesheets to your views in `app/views/posts` but I recommend you to use [**layouts**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for your application, The layouts sit in the `app/views/layouts`. You can simply create an `application.html.erb` in your layouts directory and put your CSS includes there.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "custom" %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

The yield block will contain the actual output of your views, so you should remove these parts from the existing views.

#### 3rd answer

If you want to control the accepted characters for a certain field, you could do it in a [**validation**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) in your model.

```
validates :title,
  :format => { :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/, :message => "Only letters allowed" },
  :length => { :maximum => 20 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to add columns to an existing table is to just create a new migration:

```
rails g migration add_public_and_private_to_document public:string private:string
```

If you use the `add_[column_names]_to_[model]` naming convention, Rails will work out the appropriate table and create the migration you want.

Have a read here for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new field you have to make a migration, and add the field into the _form.html.erb

```
rails generate migration add_author_to_posts author:string
```

You have to make your styles inside of app/assets/stylesheets

Read this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

And for migrations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Also, I recommend you: http://railscasts.com/

Welcome aboard!